# Changing IK/FK switch range

Tags: rigging

Would someone assist me on this ik/fk switch problem i faced.Based on the  picture, when my IK switch moves from point A to B ,its just too far to reach its FK state. Is there anyway i can decrease the range?

The rig itself, is just a small dinosaur, just as big as a 5 year old's hand size.

I also tries to use bone constraint 'limit location' to few cm, but the influence only stop to a fraction between 0 to 1 (example, 0.3) when i change the range from 1 meter to few cm.

Should i mention the rig is using Auto Rig Pro?
Thank you

Here is the blender file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a Limit Location Bone constraint, this should give you exactly what you want.
[image]

Your problem probably has to do with the default settings, you will probably need to mess with them quite a bit to get exactly what you want. But the main thing is to set the owner to *Custom Space* and then target the bone you want it to be relative to. Then if you set everything to 0,0,0 it will occupy the same exact location as the parent bone. So then just add distance in whatever axis works til you get it constrained to the exact location you want.

[image]

Comment: I tried using your solution but alas it leads to same conclusion. Basically what happens is ,for example, the range for the ik to switch to fk completely is 1m in this rig of mine. So when i decrease the range of the switch movement to 20% of the original range, which is 20cm, the influence also only reach up to 20% . I can't reach 0 to 1 influence within 20cm. the complete swithcing still based on the 1m range. I hope i explained this well. I wonder if i can submit my file for inspection?

Comment: Use this link to [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file. Then you can edit your post and paste it at the bottom.

Comment: You shouldn't be setting the Min Max XYZ to anything like my settings I posted. Check all the boxes with the Owner set like I show it and then tweak the values in Min Max XYZ to get the results you want.

Comment: thank you, i will submit the blend file for inspection as soon as i reach my studio.